# Посоветуйте студию для MySQL

Tags: mysql, ide, поиск-программ

Какие программы есть для написания запросов на MySQL. Я все время работал с Oracle и MSSQL для каждой из них есть отличные IDE. Есть ли что нибудь подобное для MySQL? так как работать через phpMyAdmin не очень удобно.

Comment: navicat https://www.navicat.com/ru/

Answer (score 3):

Пока не прикрыли лавочку с оффтопик вопросом, вот отличный вариант:
**dbForge Studio Express for MySQL**.

Comment: Благодарим за признание! Ссылка на полное описание продукта https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html

Answer (score 2):

Если вы имеете в виду графический интерфейс пользователя для MySQL, то можно посоветовать вам [**SQLyog**](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog). Его преимущества: интуитивно понятный дизайн, богатый функционал.
Также можно посоветовать посмотреть в сторону [dbForge Studio for MySQ](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/)L и [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).

Answer (score 2):

У MySQL есть отличная среда разработки [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

Любой текстовый редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса и командная строка.

Comment: Подсветка синтаксиса лишнее, лучше просто голый текст ;-)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/106045)

Comment: @rjhdby это вполне себе ответ

Comment: @Kromster это не ответ на поставленный вопрос. Автор просит подсказать специализированный инструмент для работы конкретно с MySQL. Далеко не любой текстовый редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса подойдет. Мне казалось, что stackoverflow это не то место, где глумятся и прикалываются в ответах.

Comment: @rjhdby Где ж Вы там глумление увидели? ТС задается вопросом "Какие программы есть для написания запросов на MySQL?"  Какие запросы нельзя в блокнотике написать в отличие от IDE?

Comment: @carapuz запрос можно написать и в hex-редакторе. Автор просил удобный инструмент для работы с MySQL, а не измышления на тему "IDE для неудачников, настоящие мужики пишут в vi"

Comment: @rjhdby Если ему нужен инструмент, так бы и писал. А догадываться, какие функции ему нужно выполнять, можно бесконечно. По факту задан вопрос касательно написания запросов.

Comment: @carapuz Вообще, именно так он и написал. "для каждой из них есть отличные IDE. Есть ли что нибудь подобное для MySQL". То, что текст можно писать в текстовом редакторе - это, как бы, не божественное откровение.

Comment: "просил удобный инструмент", а вот за это вопрос и закроется, ибо понятие удобности - сугубо индивидуальное.